# How to test load balancing in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I done congfiguration in nginx for redirection and it works successfully.
But in that i want load balancing :-
for that i already create **load-balancer.conf** as well as give server name into that file like :-

```
upstream backend {
  # ip_hash;

   server 1.2.3.4;
   server 5.6.7.8;
 }

server {
   listen 80;

   location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

In both instances i did same configuration 
and it default uses round-robin algorithm so in that request transfer via one pc to another pc.....
but it were not working

can any one suggest me anything that secong request going to another server 5.6.7.8

so i can check load balancing.

Thankyou so much.

Comment: You could use Apache Jmeter to test load balancing. It should give you more information about what is happening and failing. There is a tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-perform-load-testing-on-a-web-server

Comment: @BrunoB.Carvalho i already tested it in jmeter, but i want that the second request goes to 5.6.7.8 server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a log file for upstream to check request is going to which server

```
http {
   log_format upstreamlog '$server_name to: $upstream_addr {$request} '
   'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time'
   ' request_time $request_time';

upstream backend {
  # ip_hash;

   server 1.2.3.4;
   server 5.6.7.8;
 }

server {
   listen 80;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log upstreamlog;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

and then check your log file
**sudo cat /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;**

you will see log like

```
to: 5.6.7.8:80 {GET /sites/default/files/abc.png HTTP/1.1} upstream_response_time 0.171 request_time 0.171
```