# Testing load balancing in NGINX

Tags: nginx, tomcat, load-balancing

I set up load balancing on NGINX using the Round Robin for apache tomcat servers with two servers in my `proxy.conf` file:

```
upstream appcluster1 {
    server IP_ADDRESS:8000;
    server IP_ADDRESS:8001;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://appcluster1;
    }

}
```

This is deployed on the cloud and I am able to hit the endpoint using this method successfully. However, I want to test and see if nginx redirects between the two servers. How would I go about this?

I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859396/how-to-test-load-balancing-in-nginx) but I do not see anything in the logs that shows what server it is hitting. Is there any other way I can test and see if nginx would go to the second server?

EDIT: I have another file called `nginx.conf` that looks like this:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    js_include auth.js;
    proxy_buffering off;

    log_format upstreamlog '$server_name to: $upstream_addr {$request} '
    'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time'
    ' request_time $request_time';
    # log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    # '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    # '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # access_log   logs/access.log  main;
    # sendfile     on;
    #tcp_nopush   on;

    keepalive_timeout  65s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120s; 
    keepalive_requests 50;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: If you added $upstream_addr in log_format, the upstream address that served each request should appear in access.log. Exactly what log_format are you using and what is the log like in your access log?

Comment: @kelgon I have another file called `nginx.conf` that contains the log, I can update my question to show what I'm doing

Comment: I see you have log_format `upstreamlog` defined but not used. You need to relate that log_format to a log file with `access_log` directive, for example `access_log 
 logs/access.log  upstreamlog`

Comment: @kelgon Ah gotcha! Hmm so when I deploy it though, I get the following error: `2021/02/01 18:30:01 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`
`nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)` -- is there anything else I need to do for it to work when deploying it?

Comment: Make sure folder `/etc/nginx/logs` existed.